# how to parse second div class with the same class name using JSoup in android

Tags: android, jsoup

I did inspect element and I want to get the value under `"l-container"` class, but the problem is that I have multiple `"l-container"` class elements and I want to get the second nested `<div class="l-container">` only - [here is the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd1r8.jpg). How can I do it?

```
 for(int i=0;i<=newsArrayList.size();i++) {
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(newsArrayList.get(i)).get();
    final Elements content = document.getElementsByClass("l-container");
        String pConcatenated = "";
         for (Element x : content) {
              pConcatenated += x.text();
         }
            paraNewsArrayList.add(pConcatenated);
 }
```

but the problem is, I've got all div class that containts "l-container"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using following selector:

```
section.zn-body-text > div.l-container
```

You can do it by modifying line responsible for selecting all elements from `document` object:

```
final Elements content = document.select("section.zn-body-text > div.l-container");
```

According to the screenshot you have attached your second `l-container` div is a child of section with a class `zn-body-text`. You can select this element using `>` operator starting from `section.zn-body-text`. I hope it helps.

Comment: how will I do that using Jsoup? I will add my code above

Comment: @user7415379 I've updated my answer. Please let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: @user7415379 Cool, I'm glad I could help you :)